# Cannot replace pointer via a struct method

Tags: pointers, go, slice

Got a struct method that returns a pointer:

```
func (d *DataMap) Get(p Coord) *CellData {
    return &d.Data[p.X+(p.Y*d.Size)]
}
```

The d.Data is an array of CellData which is a struct with several fields. With this method I can modify the inner value of each field, ie:

```
example.Get(p).Something = 123
```

But I cannot do something like this:

```
example.Get(p) = *yada (yada is a *CellData)
```

Where I want to replace the pointer with another pointer I get:

```
cannot assign to example.Get(p)(undefined)
```

What am I doing wrong? The output of the function is defined, dont' know why I'm getting that error. Right now I fixed this by accessing the array directly.

Thanks.

Comment: Wonder why my question got downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get` returns a pointer, so if you want to store into whatever that pointer is pointing to, you need to add a `*` (pointer dereference) at the beginning:

```
*(example.Get(p)) = *yada
```

Comment: Ahhh, tried that but without the external parenthesis. Thanks!